# Maven plugin AEM 6.1

Tags: maven

I am getting error on running

```
mvn install -PautoInstallPackage
```

in maven AEM. Getting error:

> "unresolvable build extension: Plugin com.day.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.24 or one of the dependencies could not be resolved".

Comment: Go through Documentation [How to ask on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a query

Comment: Any solution to the problem of maven?